# W3 Total Cache not minified only couple of CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, minify, w3-total-cache

I am currently using W3 Total Cache on a large WordPress site, I have a couple of plugins and assets from theme which needs to be minified.

I see that CSS are being combined but not all of them are minified, CSS file which originally wasn't minified is only combined into the one big file.

Any ideas why W3 Total Cache does that?

Answer (score 1):

Nope wp-total-cache will not minify , you need to use [Better WordPress Minify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/)

This will cache the css with minified version , so once you purge the cache , you can see all the changes.

Comment: I did try this Better WordPress Minify, same issue. Couple of assets are still not minified, and I'm getting a bad score on Google Page Insights. I have tried WP Super Minify as well.